# HTML5 boilertemplate

Tags: html, css

I integrated html boilertemplate with the help of the initializr on my side.
Now, i tried to add sub ul elements to the navigation in form of a dropdown, that got created by the initializr with pure css3, but i can't get it to work.

The css from boilertemplate created for the nav element is the following:

```
nav ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

nav a {
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 15px 0;

 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;

 color: white;
 background: green;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:visited {
 color: white;
}

nav a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {

/* ====================
    INTERMEDIATE: Menu
   ==================== */

nav a {
    float: left;
    width: 13%;
    margin: 0 1.7%;
    padding: 10px 2%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

nav li:first-child a {
    margin-left: 0;
}

nav li:last-child a {
    margin-right: 0;
}

/* ========================
    INTERMEDIATE: IE Fixes
   ======================== */

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
}

.oldie nav a {
    margin: 0 0.7%;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    nav {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

The solution i tried did not work with css3 from: 
http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

How can i add sub elements / sub ul's to the navigation , so that they are displayed in a drop down to the hovered element?

In the end, i hoped it would have worked like in their example:
http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/css-menu/demo/index.html

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some key CSS rules. Specifically:

```
nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
}
```

Also, what is your html? Can't you simply copy and paste the code from the example you have linked to?

Comment: I added this to my code now:    
    nav ul ul {
        display: none;
    }

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }


the sub ul elements fade in and out, but not like a dropdown. How can i style this now?
I can't copy the whole css, because there is a lot other stuff in there, i picked out all that relates to nav element

--
My html is just ul nested in another ul with li elements.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Taken from the link you have provided, this should give you the desired effect; change values as needed.

```
nav ul ul {
display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}


nav ul {
background: #efefef; 
background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
padding: 0 20px;
border-radius: 10px;  
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
    nav ul li:hover {
        background: #4b545f;
        background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
    }
        nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #fff;
        }

    nav ul li a {
        display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
        color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
    }


nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
    nav ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a; position: relative;
    }
        nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 15px 40px;
            color: #fff;
        }   
            nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #4b545f;
            }

nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

Comment: if the html helps:
    <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="left"><a href="../">Mainpage</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="left"><a href="Test">
Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Tester</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Test</a></li>

Comment: <li><a href="">Test2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Test3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Other stuff</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

Comment: Try this:nav ul ul {
position: absolute;
left:-9999px;
} 
nav ul li:hover > ul {
left: 0px; 
}